# How useful is dynamic-wind in real world programming?

Tags: scheme

I have read a bit and tried to understand `dynamic-wind` but am not quite sure how it can be employed in a real world application.

Any insight on the subject will be very helpful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first thing that comes to mind is [Olegs argument against call/cc](http://okmij.org/ftp/continuations/against-callcc.html) which also mentions Dynamic wind "pros" and cons. It's mostly negative so it will be interesting to see if anyone else answers with other material.

Comment: I finally got around to reading the link you provided. It explains things with a lot greater depth than I can follow at the moment but it does make some sense. Thanks.